# How do I know if the IRS processed my money order?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, payment

I'm an international student currently living in the US on F-1 status. And recently I filed my tax forms along with a money order with USPS priority mail to the IRS in North Carolina.

How do I check if my money order is processed by the IRS, and in the case where the money order isn't processed, will it be returned to me. And if so, how do I track the return mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can check your IRS account online](https://www.irs.gov/payments/view-your-tax-account).

The caveat is that it can take a few weeks for it to show up there.

Keep in mind that it is tax season and things can take longer to process, especially things sent through the mail that require an actual person to handle and deal with.

To their credit, the IRS is pretty good about keeping track of stuff and if for some reason your money order could not be processed I imagine they would send it back to the return address; I'm not sure exactly though and it may depend on why exactly it couldn't be processed.

You won't be able to track the return mail, because it would be a new mailing most likely sent "first class" which is not a trackable service of the USPS.

Comment: Hi. I cannot register for an IRS account, because they need my credit card number or mortgage account. I tried to use my credit card number, but it says that the number doesn't match their records. I'm not sure what to do